# Why was Marla's life in danger according to The Narrator?

Tags: plot-explanation, fight-club

In the film *Fight Club*,  What I understood so far is that The Narrator thinks Marla's life in danger because Tyler wants to kill her.

In the scene where The Narrator realizes he's also Tyler and they have a discussion, Tyler says "Now you see our dilemma, she know too much.". 
And I get that Tyler didn't want The Narrator to realize they were the same person (and so not to talk about Tyler to Marla) because The Narrator didn't have the balls to do on his own what Tyler did.

But how is Marla compromising any plans at that point of the movie ?

The Narrator already understood he's Tyler so what is there that Marla could ruin ?

Answer (score 3):

The most overlooked thing in this movie.

Marla is narratively Tyler's opposition. Tyler is the explosive, self destructive, hyper macho man baby. Marla is communication, trust, she shares her vulnerabilities and insecurities. Some have also characterised her as his guilt. (Some have suggested she may also be another symptom of his breakdown. Marla walks through traffic, steals food and clothing, is a woman smoking at the men only cancer support group and is never challenged for any of this, in fact she is rarely looked at or spoken to.) She calls up to say she is scared (having found a lump) because she is the importance of being able to ask for help. She is a mess, but life is a mess. Tyler is hot and needs no one, for he is manly, but this is a seductive fantasy image of self assuredness.

The narrator's relationships with these two characters is a conflict between two competing energies. Will he open himself up to vulnerability or will he be seduced by the power of the hyper-macho.

Marla is keeping the narrator from completely embracing Tyler, her (arguably positive) influence endangers Tyler's grip on the narrator and in turn Operation Mayhem.

The movie ends with a realisation that he must stop being scared and passive, he must stop following (and being bullied by) the cool-kid Tyler. But to break Tyler's spell he must be brave and take responsibility for a bold action () even if it is painful (aka a hole in the face). As soon as his rejection of Tyler's energy is complete the Elevator doors open and he is reunited with Marla, accepting her energy and completing his journey.

I'll add this though. There will be a lot of `yeah but what about...` questions arising from this answer but you have to remember you are seeing the world through the eyes of a man in the middle of a crushing mental breakdown, he is the most unreliable narrator you'll find.

Comment: Upvote for that suggestion in the spoiler box. This is one of my all-time favourite films and I've seen it dozens of times, yet never considered that as a possibility.

Comment: I don't think the spoiler markup is required - anyone reading an answer on Fight Club and has not seen the movie or is not interested in further analysis on it deserves it.  Great answer though.

Comment: Likewise I have never considered this way of looking at Marla.  I'm not sure that Marla is quite the vulnerable, insecure person that you suggest, her actions indicate someone who is very secure in herself - she takes what she wants, and is happy to call the narrator an asshole when he gaslights her - but its undeniable that her influence on him is positive.

Comment: @iandotkelly yes I'd absolutely agree with you there. I may have overstated. I'd say she is vulnerable and insecure (suicide attempts, attention seeking, calls herself infectious human waste) but you are right that she is certainly not passive or weak, as I said, she is real and real is messy :) a bit piece of the narrators starting point is his passiveness and the two competing energies are both non-passive but one is a clear cut and self assured fantasy, the other a messy complicated real life human connection.

Comment: Vulnerable, as in she allows herself to be vulnerable, in a good sense, like a building block of human relationships is to allow the people close to you to see you and your flaws, and to tell them when you're scared. She invites him over to 'check her', a pretty scary move.

Comment: Updated answer :-*

Answer (score 2):

Even though Tyler is part of the Narrator, that part (which we call Tyler) has an **agenda**, which we see represented as Tyler's proactive "teaching" of the Narrator. You've touched on this in your question:

> Tyler didn't want The Narrator to realize they were the same person because The Narrator didn't have the balls to do on his own what Tyler did.

If Tyler didn't want the Narrator to be aware of the split personalities, why on Earth would he trust *Marla* with that same knowledge, which gives her the power to ruin Tyler's agenda?

*Note: your question seems to imply that the Narrator's realization (about Tyler) is the biggest problem for Tyler. It is not. It is **a** problem, but there is a threat of something much more dangerous to Tyler: a psychiatric hospital and anti-psychotic meds. The Narrator's knowledge about Tyler is only an obstacle (to Tyler's teachings), but the hospital and meds will drive Tyler out completely.*

Marla being aware of Tyler being the Narrator (or vice versa, I guess) means that she's in a unique position. The guys in the club generally think of the Narrator as a guy with some serious balls (= Tyler), but they don't realize that it's a matter of split personalities.

As such, Marla is the only one who can really pull the emergency brake, call in a psychiatrist, and put an end to Tyler's agenda. This is why she's a threat to Tyler.

And there's a great duality here, because before the Narrator realizes he is Tyler, he interprets Tyler's words differently.

- Pre-realization, he can interpret Tyler's words as Marla being dangerous because she knows too much about the fight club and its dealings.
- Post-realization, we now know that Tyler thinks of Marla as a threat, because she can put a stop to the psychological manifestation that is Tyler (or at least his agenda).

> **edit**
>   Just a realization. Tyler seeing Marla as a threat indirectly confirms that *Tyler knows he's inside the Narrator's head*, even though the Narrator himself is not initially aware of it.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your answer ! That theory makes sense so i believe that's that since there's no other theory explaining it

But it's not really explained clearly or even implied in the movie, before Marla gets in the bus she says "Why am I a threat ?" and Tyler says "I'll explain to you later" but we never have a clear explanation :/

(1/2)

Comment: Also regarding Tyler's agenda, that makes a lot of sense cause see how The Narrator kept searching for Tyler but Tyler never showed up until soon before the explosion ? I think it was Tyler's plan to get re-united since the Narrator only needed Tyler to do the things he didn't have the balls to do and that the main goal was achieved (also the narrator grew to be more and more the way he actually wanted to be, which is Tyler).

So maybe Tyler did expect to be killed. Or maybe he just wanted to simply live with the Narrator again without hiding, and so he actually planned to kill Marla.
(2/2)

Comment: Actually one more thing, anybody who could've called the Narrator Tyler would've been a problem to them then, so why especially Marla ?
The Narrator also didn't seem to notice when people would call him by his name if Tyler didn't want to, it only happened when Tyler prepared to appear, so why is Marla a problem still ?

Comment: @Garbage: The fact that we never hear the Narrator's name, highly suggests that he usually doesn't get addressed. Which fits with his initial pre-Tyler life; he sort of blends into the background and feels futile because of it. It's likely that his outgoing nature (interacting with people) has predominantly been driven by Tyler during the movie. And keep in mind that when Tyler is controlling the Narrator, that there's obviously no issue with him being called Tyler. It's also possible that when the N got called Tyler (even when he wasn't Tyler at the time), that Tyler would "activate".